# Listening to Map Entries with Predicates doesn't fire

Tags: c#, hazelcast

I try to use [map listener with predicates](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Data_Structures/Map/Listening_to_Map_entries_with_Predicates.html) like on docs.

I am using .net 3.9 client and I configured my Java (also Hazelcast 3.9) code. But my listeners doesn't fire.

```
myTestMap.AddEntryListener(new EntryAdapter<string,MyTestMap> { Added = e => ValidateData(e) },new SqlPredicate("Status=2"),true);
```

> When old value does not match predicate, new value matches predicate

writes on document. But any event fire include with have no predicate.

**UPDATE:** I update version 3.9.1 and try to use `EntryAddedListener`.
I update code;

```
myTestMap.AddEntryListener(new TestListener(),new SqlPredicate("Status=2"),true);
public class TestListener: EntryAddedListener<string,MyTestMap> {
    public void EntryAdded(EntryEvent<string,MyTestMap> @event) {
         ValidateData(@event);
    }
}
```

This time, I get:

> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

**UPDATE 2:** Ok, I found the problem and try to fix it.

```
ClientMapProxy.AddEntryListener(MapListener listener,.....
```

methods has recursive call so, I get previous exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're usage is exactly correct and is expected to work. From looking at our Github repository, I see you've already figured it really is a bug and reported it (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client/issues/145) thanks for it.

For the sake of others running into the same issue, we're looking into fixing it, please see the issue linked above.

Thanks again for the report and your digging into it!